# How to disable authorization middleware in cakePHP4?

Tags: cakephp, authorization, middleware, cakephp-4.x

By default, the authorization plugin is apply to a global scope.  For some controllers that I did not want to apply any authorization.  I have to use the `skipAuthorization` config manually for each action.  For authentication plugin, I can just only load the authentication component for each controller that requires authentication.  However, the authorization middleware seems will always work even if I did not load the authorization component in the controller.  So, why is that?  And is there a way I can disable the authorization process for the entire controller?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean Authentication and not Authorization. In any case, from the Docs:

```
// in src/Controller/AppController.php
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
}
```

> By default the component will require an authenticated user for all
> actions. You can disable this behavior in specific controllers using
> allowUnauthenticated():

```
// in a controller beforeFilter or initialize // Make view and index not require a logged in user.
$this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['view', 'index']);
```

More information: [The Authentication plugin in the Cake Book](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not doing it in the right way. For authorization, you have to write a request policy. Whenever you bake controller just add --prefix Admin or whatever you want to.

```
cake bake controller Users --prefix Admin
```

Put all admin controllers in one place.
Add routes in your routes file

```
$builder->prefix('Admin',['_namePrefix' => 'admin:'], function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
    $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'Index']);
    $builder->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

`
Request Policy. Create a role table and add column role_id in the Users table and the rest you will understand with code below.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Policy;

use Authorization\IdentityInterface;
use Authorization\Policy\RequestPolicyInterface;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
class RequestPolicy implements RequestPolicyInterface
{
    /**
     * Method to check if the request can be accessed
     *
     * @param IdentityInterface|null Identity
     * @param ServerRequest $request Server Request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canAccess($identity, ServerRequest $request)
    {
        $role = 0;
        if(!empty($identity)){
            $data = $identity->getOriginalData();
            $role = $data['role_id'];
        } 
         if(!empty($request->getParam('prefix'))){
            switch($request->getParam('prefix')){
                        case 'User' : return (bool)($role === 3);
                        case 'Admin': return (bool)($role === 1) || (bool)($role === 2);
                            
            }
            
         }else{
             return true;
         }
         
        return false;
        
    }
}
```

`

and then implements AuthorizationServiceProviderInterface to the Application

```
use App\Policy\RequestPolicy;
use Authorization\AuthorizationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authorization\AuthorizationService;
use Authorization\Policy\MapResolver;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class Application extends BaseApplication implements AuthorizationServiceProviderInterface{
public function getAuthorizationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthorizationServiceInterface
    {
        $mapResolver = new MapResolver();
        $mapResolver->map(ServerRequest::class, RequestPolicy::class);
        return new AuthorizationService($mapResolver);
    }
}
```